# Can you help identify this tree from my garden?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees

The picture is an evergreen tree.

I have seen very similar trees in Northern Italy. I would appreciate any help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Do you have any idea if this tree is native (have you seen very similar trees around) or do you think the seed / tuber have been imported from elsewhere and planted here?

Comment: Can you provide a close up of the leaves/branches? IMO, it's difficult to determine otherwise.

Comment: The tree in the picture is growing in dublin, Ireland. Most likely imported ad I have never seen them here before (not an expert) but I have seen what look the same in northern Italy

Answer (score 4):

It's a Juniper, genus *Juniperus*.

If will feel prickly, and if you run your hand along the branch from the out to the inside it will feel very prickly. If you run your hand in to out, it will be marginally less so, but still uncomfortable,

Crushing the leaves in your fingers will release a sharp, tangy, not unpleasant smell.

Juniper *Juniperus communis* is native to some parts of in England, Scotland and Wales, and north and west of Ireland, and in fact most of the temperate forest regions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniperus_communis#/media/File:Juniperus_communis_range_map.png

The berries are used to flavour gin.

However there are many other species of *Juniperus* that are often planted as ornamental trees, so it could well be one of these. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniper

Best way for a positive ID is take a small bit with you to a large garden centre, or arboretum, and head to the juniper section and compare the look, feel and smell of the specimens.